# React Apollo Cache updating delay after mutation to load new image

Tags: apollo-client, react-apollo, apollo-cache-inmemory

I do mutation to upload image as a result one url of type string changes to another in Apollo Cache.
Delay is taking around 0,5 sec to update client cache.
Problem: we show loader during image mutation is loading, after loading is done - old picture appears for few milliseconds, and after new one appears. So we have not beautiful blinking image after update.

What is the best way to go?

Comment: can you provide code related to how you have configured apollo, and also can provide minimum reproducible code?